# Create block 'customer/form_register' on account login page

Tags: magento, block, registration

I need to show registration fields on account/login page in Magento.
I try this method

```
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml"/>
        <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

But this method show registration fields after login fields.

And this `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_register')->toHtml() ?>` don't work.

I can't understand what I do wrong?

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put something like this in your xml

```
   <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" >
        <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml" />
                       </block>
```

Put register block under login block so register block will display inside login box not after login fields.

And put this code inside your `login.phtml` file wherever you want

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer_form_register'); ?>` this will call your register block inside `login.phtml` file.

You need to change design settings in `register.phtml` file so I recommend to use another `register.phtml` file .

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, use this in your local.xml file:

```
<customer_account_login>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml" before="customer_form_login"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

You set the register form in the login content layout and use the `before="customer_form_login"` to place it before the login box.